# How to use subsubsection in "moderncv" class?

Tags: sectioning

How to put subsubsection in "moderncv" class? Only upto subsection is working in my script.

Comment: What `\moderncvstyle` are you using? In fact, you should at least consider the community by posting what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. It'll give us the foundation form which we can provide solutions.

Comment: What does mean `working`? Is `subsubsection` known at all?

Comment: An alternative for you could be `komacv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sectioning commands in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) are only defined down to `\subsection`, so you'll have to define it manually.

Below I've added `\subsubsection`s which mimic `\subsection` in its layout except for the font (given by the macro `\subsubsectionfont`). Add the following to your document preamble *after* loading your `\moderncvstyle`:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\newcommand*{\subsubsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\itshape}% New subsubsection font
\newcommand*{\subsubsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsubsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#2}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{} &{\strut\subsubsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{0.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

Example output using `\moderncvstyle{casual}` in the `blue` theme:

[image]

```
...
\section{References}
\subsection{Sub-references}
\subsubsection{Sub-sub-references}
...
```

The above `\subsubsection` definition should work under the `classic` style as well, but not `banking`.

Comment: How to use it for `banking`?

Comment: Looks like a little big, no?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Werner's answer: as well as defining `\subsubsection` document command (see their answer), you might also want to increment the default bookmark depth set by `moderncv`.

Otherwise, subsubsections won't show in the PDF bookmarks.

```tex
\AtEndPreamble{
  \hypersetup{
    bookmarksdepth = 3
  }}
```