# How to customize subsection in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I want to add subsection in `moderncv` class which starts at the beginning of the line with a symbol such as a bullet or circ, or anything else which is in harmony with the `moderncv` layout. Or how can I draw a `\hline` (and in the same color of background)?

I have already read [How to use subsubsection in "moderncv" class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213872/how-to-use-subsubsection-in-moderncv-class), but this is not what I'm searching for.

What I have is something like this

[image]

with the code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
 \moderncvstyle{casual} 
 \moderncvcolor{grey} 
 \usepackage{lipsum} 
 \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
 \firstname{xxx} 
 \familyname{xxx} 
 \title{Research Statement}

 \begin{document}
 \makecvtitle 

 \section{Section}

 \subsection{Subsection}

 \lipsum

 \end{document}
```

But, I want to have e.g. something like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the definition for commands `\section` and `\subsection` for style `casual` is

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
```

Now we can create a new command `\mysubsection` to get what you want. I just added the command for the horizontal rule with half the length of `\hintscolumnwidth` to the command and deleted the usage of command `\cvitem`, which builds the two columns for rule and text:

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  {\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{0.5\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}\quad}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

Commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because `@` is used in the code above.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % head [left,right] 2, body 1, foot 1
\moderncvcolor{grey} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  {\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{0.5\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}\quad}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe} 
\title{Research Statement}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle 

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\mysubsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Great! That's what I needed! Danke!